# Setting number format for with chart.set_table

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am generating a column chart with the Xlsxwriter.
I would like for the numbers under the chart be formatted as %'s rather the the default format

[Current formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djmVM.jpg)

The code I am using looks like:

```
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'data_labels': {'value': True} })
chart.set_plotarea ({'layout': { 'width':10 , 'height': 10 } })
chart.set_table({'show_keys': True})
chart.set_title({ 'name': sheetName + ' QOR Trend', 'name_font': { 'name': 'Calibri', 'color': 'black', }, })
```

How do I change the table data to "0.00%"